# Code structure needed to catch exceptions from CloseableHttpClient.execute()

Tags: java, scala, apache-httpclient-4.x

Given,

```
val request: HttpPost = new HttpPost(url)
val response: CloseableHttpResponse = client.execute(request)
```

How do I arrange them using try catch blocks so that I can catch the exceptions properly?

[Here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient.html#execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest)) it says that `execute()` can throw 2 exceptions so I tried doing

```
val client: CloseableHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
    try{
      val response: CloseableHttpResponse = client.execute(request)
    }catch {
      case ClientProtocolException => println("Excepton1")
      case IOException => println("Exception2")
    }finally {
      response.close()
      client.close()
    }
```

but this is not valid since `response` is not resolved in the `finally` block since it was declared in `try`.

Any solution which does not make me use `var`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're looking for something similar to try-with-resources from java, in scala you can use `scala.util.Using`. Here is an example usage for your case

```
  val url = ""
  val request: HttpPost = new HttpPost(url)

  Using.Manager { use =>
    val client: CloseableHttpClient = use(HttpClientBuilder.create().build())
    val response: CloseableHttpResponse = use(client.execute(request))
  }.recover {
    case ClientProtocolException => println("Excepton1")
    case IOException => println("Exception2")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A catch block can name the exception it catches, as in

catch (SQLException e) {
....
}

So you can have multiple catch blocks addressing different exceptions.

Comment: except it would be written `catch { case e: SQLException => ... }`.